# Print the data, shape, and dtype of a numpy array in one statement

Tags: python, numpy

I often want to see the `shape`, `dtype`, and partial contents of a `numpy` array.

This can be done using:

```
print(x.shape, x.dtype, x)
```

However, if `x` is a long expression, this becomes awkward.

Is there perhaps an easy way to achieve this type of output using a built-in `ndarray` attribute or `numpy` function?  (Obviously, one can create a custom function but I hope to avoid this.)

Comment: Not really.  Sometimes I use `x.__array_interface__` but that gives more than shape and dtype (and none of the values).

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the possibly long output of the array you could (temporarily) set the [`threshold` print option](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions):

> **thresholdint, optional**
> Total number of array elements which trigger summarization rather than full repr (default 1000). To always use the full repr without
> summarization, pass sys.maxsize.

Example to set it temporarily using a context manager:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100)

with np.printoptions(threshold=5):
    print(x.shape, x.dtype, np.array_repr(x))
#(100,) int32 array([ 0,  1,  2, ..., 97, 98, 99])
```

(using [`np.array_repr(x)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_repr.html#numpy-array-repr) instead of simply `x` also shows you the type of array, i.e. array or MaskedArray)

You could also set your own [string function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_string_function.html#numpy-set-string-function):

```
def info(x):
    with np.printoptions(threshold=5):
        return f'{x.shape} {x.dtype} {np.array_repr(x)}'
        
np.set_string_function(info)
```

so that simply typing the variable name in the console returns your custom string representation:

```
In [1]: x
Out[1]: (100,) int32 array([ 0,  1,  2, ..., 97, 98, 99])
```